# How to prove properties about a specific modular arithmetic equivalence

Tags: proof-techniques, modular-arithmetic

Ever since I was introduced to modular arithmetic, I've had some trouble with it. I think it uses a part of my brain that I haven't used often. Anyways, I've been thinking about this specific equivalence: 
$$a^3 \equiv 5 \, (\text{mod } 7)$$
And I have a hunch that no $a$ exists s.t. this equivalence is true. Simulating it, it's clear that there is a pattern: 6, 1, 6, 6, 0, **1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 6, 0,** 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 6, 0...

But I can't figure out how to formally prove 1. that this pattern is the actual pattern and as an extension, 2. that the equivalence above doesn't hold (it should be trivial if I can prove 1).

Can anyone help? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove it by calculating the value of $a^3 \bmod 7$ for $a=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$; if none of those yield 5, then you have proven the claim.

Why is this sufficient?  Well, if $a \equiv b \pmod 7$, then $a^3 \equiv b^3 \pmod 7$.  So, if there was any solution to $a^3 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$, then you could take $b = a \bmod 7$, and that would be another solution.  Now $b$ is one of $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$, so we've proven that if there is any solution, then one of $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ must be a solution.  Conversely, if none of $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ is a solution, then there is no solution whatsoever.

For the special case of squaring (rather than cubing), you might be interested in [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity), which is a more advanced technique that allows to check for the existence of solutions to such an equation.  There is also [cubic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity), though I'm not sure whether it leads to an efficient algorithm to check for solutions when you have a cube instead of a square.

Comment: Apparently [cubic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity) is a thing.

Comment: @AaronRotenberg, thanks!

Comment: I guess my misunderstanding is more fundamental. Why have we proven the claim if we've only tried 0 through 6? It's obvious that $a^1$ modulo 7 would "loop" back around, but how do we know it loops back around in the case of a cube?

Comment: @CoolRobloxKid12, ahh, that makes sense.  See 2nd paragraph of my edited answer for an explanation of that point.

Comment: @D.W. Despite knowing how to prove it, I have long considered the fact that modular multiplication "works" - i.e., that $(ab) \text{ mod }m = [(a \text{ mod }m) (b \text{ mod }m)] \text{ mod }m$ - to be rather magical.

Comment: @D.W. There's still a few gaps that I don't quite understand. 1. I understand that if $a \equiv b (\bmod 7)$, then $a^3 \equiv b^3 (\bmod 7)$. But is the opposite direction true as well? 2. when you say you could take $b = a \bmod 7$, how do we know it's a solution? I assume it has to do with $a \equiv b (\bmod 7)$ but I think there's a bit of notation confusion here...

Comment: @CoolRobloxKid12, no, the opposite direction does not hold (consider that $1^3 \equiv 2^3 \pmod 7$), but we don't need it to.  We know it's a solution because if you take $b = a \bmod 7$, then by construction $b \equiv a \pmod 7$; it follows that $b^3 \equiv a^3 \pmod 7$ (the magical fact that Aaron Rotenberg mentions); now since we know $a^3 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$, it follows that $b^3 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$, so $b$ is a solution, too.

Comment: ah, I get it now. thank you so much for walking me through this.