# What is the time complexity of determining whether a solution $x$ exists to $x^k \equiv c \pmod{N}$ if we know the factorization of $N$?

Tags: time-complexity, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose we are given an integer $c$ and positive integers $k, N$, with no further assumptions on relationships between these numbers. We are also given the prime factorization of $N$. These inputs are written in binary. What is the best known time complexity for determining whether there exists an integer $x$ such that $x^k \equiv c \pmod{N}$?

We are given the prime factorization of $N$ because this problem is thought to be hard on classical computers [even for *k* = 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residuosity_problem) if we do not know the factorization of $N$.

This question was inspired by [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/118538/8311), where D.W. stated that the nonexistence of a solution to $x^3 \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$ can be checked by computing the modular exponentiation for $x = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6$, but that if the exponent had been 2 instead of 3, we could have used quadratic reciprocity instead. This lead to my discovery that there are a large number of other [reciprocity laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_law), such as *cubic reciprocity*, *quartic reciprocity*, *octic reciprocity*, etc. with their own Wikipedia pages.

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is prime, then $x^k\equiv c \pmod p$ has a solution if and only if $c^{(p-1)/g} \equiv 1$ where $g=\gcd(k,p-1)$.  The solution is given by $x \equiv \sqrt[g]{c^h} \pmod p$ where $h^{-1} \equiv k/g \pmod{p-1}$.  You can take $g$th roots in polynomial time using an extension of the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm); see [On taking roots in Finite Fields](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/b2hd-AMM77.html) by Adleman, Manders, and Miller.  (Strictly speaking, this algorithm requires either reasonable number theoretic assumptions or randomization.)  Given one solution $x$, the other solutions will have the form $x \beta^i$ where $\beta$ is an element of order $g$ modulo $p$.

If $p^m$ is a prime power and $\gcd(p,k)=1$, then you can use [Hensel lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) to test whether $x^k \equiv c \pmod{p^m}$ has a solution.  In particular, let $x_i=x \bmod p^i$ and $c_i=c \bmod p^i$ and $y_i = (x_{i+1} - x_i)/p$ and $d_i = (c_{i+1} - c_i)/p$.  Now find $x_1$ such that $x_1^k \equiv c_1 \pmod p$.  If this has no solution, then neither does $x^k \equiv c \pmod{p^m}$, so we can terminate immediately.  Otherwise, we're next going to try to find $x_2$ such that $x_2^k \equiv c_2 \pmod{p^2}$.  Writing $x_2 = x_1 + p y_1$ and $c_2 = c_1 + p d_1$, we obtain the equation

$$(x_1 + y_1 p)^k \equiv (c_1 + d_1 p) \pmod{p^2},$$

or equivalently,

$$k x_1 y_1 \equiv (c_1 - x_1^k)/p + d_1 \pmod p.$$

If $k x_1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, then we can let $y_1 = ((c_1 - x_1^k)/p  + d_1) \cdot (k x_1)^{-1} \bmod p$ and we have a solution for $x_2$.  Otherwise, test whether $x_1^k \equiv c_2 \pmod{p^2}$; if it is, then setting $x_2=x_1$ gives a solution, otherwise there is no solution and we can terminate.  Repeat the same process to find $x_3$, then $x_4$, etc., until you have found $x_m$.  While there may be multiple possible solutions for $x_1$, there is no need to branch and try all of them, because either all will be extendable to $x_m$ or none will.

I am not sure what to do if $\gcd(p,k)=1$.  Perhaps someone else can fill in this gap.

If $N$ is a product of prime powers $p_1^{m_1} \cdots p_n^{m_n}$, then you can use the Chinese remainder theorem to check for a root modulo each of the $p_j^{m_j}$.  A root exists modulo $N$ if and only if it exists modulo each prime power; and once you've found a solution for each prime power, you can combine them with the CRT to obtain a solution modulo $N$.

---

Proof for first paragraph: If $p$ is prime, then there exists an element $\alpha$ of order $p-1$; assuming $x \equiv \alpha^X \pmod p$ and $c \equiv \alpha^C \pmod p$, we find that the equation has a solution if and only if $Xk \equiv C \pmod{p-1}$ has a solution, which is equivalent to the stated condition in the first paragraph.

Comment: That's a pretty nice pile of number theory for an answer that doesn't even cover all the cases! 